# Azure LUIS - Prebuilt Geography Entity Alternative

Tags: azure, nlp, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am creating an Azure LUIS app that needs to recognize locations in utterances, for example: "I need a list of all employees currently in Seattle." I do not have an exhaustive list of locations as they change often due to the nature of the business.

Using the prebuilt entity builtin.geography would be ideal, but it has been deprecated and I cannot add it to my app. The  closest thing I found was Calendar.Location (a prebuilt domain) but I am not sure if I can use it for this purpose. Any advice? What is everybody using as an alternative to the Geography entity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A phrase list of locations, not too exhaustive, would help. At the same time, add Calendar.Location. Depending on the utterance, one or the other might be better to use. Also try LUIS's prebuilt keyPhrase entity. That picks up locations as well.

Comment: I will try those. Thanks, I appreciate it!